# Styling issues with <legend> tag and grid system in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

It is supposed to display this way:

[image: original]

Instead it is displaying in this way:

[image: desired look]

See the the word fruit is out of alignment.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 alpha v6. Here's the code

```
<fieldset class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><legend class="col-form-legend">Fruit</legend></div>
    <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
        <div class="form-check row">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="legendradio" id="legendradio1" value="1">Apple
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check row">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="legendradio" id="legendradio2" value="2">Orange
            </label>    
        </div>
        <div class="form-check row">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="legendradio" id="legendradio3" value="1">Watermelon
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do padding to the following html elements by adding a class to:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 padding"><legend class="col-form-legend">Fruit</legend></div>
```

AND

```
<fieldset class="form-group row padding">
```

CSS:   .padding { padding:Npx }